# UNITY - Makes AR camera scan image targets first and go to another scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I make a AR camera which you can scan an image target and go to the another scene?
No animation or whatsoever, just scan the image and go to another scene on unity.

I tried using eventHandler. Not working

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the documentation of AR Foundation or try any sample that you can find from internet. If you are building using AR Foundation, you should know there's TrackedImageInfoManager. You can try under void UpdateInfo(ARTrackedImage trackedImage), if (trackedImage.referenceImage.name == "AnythingMatchWhatYouWant") and then SceneManager.LoadScene(//you scene build index), given that you already have your own AR image library in ARTrackedImageManager.